# Faster alternative to Get-ChildItem -Recurse

Tags: powershell

I have a script that uses Get-ChildItem to find specific files in a directory. I then use two different SQL tables to compare those files with constraints and delete the files if they meet certain criteria.

Basically this is what happens:

-- For reference the -include $include variable is a unique id (string) used as the filename. I'm deleting all files similar to that name.

Example:

```
$include: 9d3aa8ee-e60e-4b4f-9cd0-6678f8a5549e*.*
```

Query table #1, put results in an array. 
Query table #2, put results in an array.

~~~ **Psuedo code** ~~~

```
    foreach ($i in table #1) {
        foreach ($x in table #2) {

            if (constraints are met) {
                $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path  -Recurse -include $include | foreach-object -process { $_.FullName }

                Delete the files
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem: There are approximately 14 million files on this server. 
I've run the script on a test server with about 1.5 million files, and it takes almost two hours.

I tried to run this script on the live server, but after three days it still had not completed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you, you're recursing over a huge directory for each file pattern you want to remove. If that's the case then I would find all patterns first and only then use a single Get-ChildItem call to remove the files.

```
$include = foreach( $i in table #1 ) 
{
    foreach( $x in table #2 ) 
    {    
       if(constraints are met) 
       {
           output file pattern
       }    

    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Include $include| Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Awesome Idea. I'll try that and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: The problem of taking too long still exists here. I'm getting an estimated run time of around 47 hours even when I split it up. Finding the list of patterns doesn't take long at all, but it still takes almost 2 days to recurse the system with Get-ChildItem.

Answer (score 1):

For just getting the fullname strings from large directory structures, the legacy DIR command with the /B switch can be much faster:

```
cmd /c dir $path\9d3aa8ee-e60e-4b4f-9cd0-6678f8a5549e*.* /b /s /a-d
```

Comment: I'm really new at all this, so I'm not following completely. Will this method search for all files 8c3aa8ee-e60e-4e9f-9cd0-6678f8a2249e*.* contained withing the directory as well as the files in any sub folder inside the root folder?

I tried the code you listed, but I get a cmd.exe : File Not Found error.

Comment: The's just the old DOS dir command. The cmd /c is necessary to force it to use that from Powershell because 'dir' is aliased to get-childitem. I didn't notice you also wanted the subdirectories. I updated the command with the /s switch that will make it recursive.

Comment: Unfortunately, after testing this script it ran for 8:15 on a test directory of 79 files (42 folders, 2.37 MB), so I don't think it's going to be much faster in this case since the live server is 14 million files and 850 GB.

Comment: It shouldn't be taking that long.  Are you running this locally, or removely via a UNC path?

Comment: I'm connected remotely to a server where the script is running, but the actual script is running on locally on that server.

As I said before, I'm really new to powershell, so I could unknowingly be doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you RDP to that server and run that from a command prompt (doesn't need to be a powershell console) and see how long it takes?

Comment: Ok, I ran that attempt on the smaller test server and as best as I can estimate, it cuts the run down to about 8.5 hours. So that will probably work! I'm going to run it on the actual server and see what the final time is. Thanks!

Comment: Another problem: If the file I'm looking for doesn't exist, I get an error. There are certain files that have already been deleted so this is going to happen. Is there a way to void the error?

Comment: It's not really an error.  The command will return the string 'File Not Found' if it didn't find anything. Just add a test for that (e.g. if ($files -eq 'File Not Found'){Write-debug "No files matching $x were found"} else {delete files}

Answer (score 0):

With 14 million files to work with, just how long does it take to find one such file?

You may simply be fighting with the I/O subsystem and the choice of script might not matter as much.

My suggestion is to baseline the single file removal to see if you can accomplish this task reasonably, or you may need to look at your hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what you mean by some constraints. But a couple of years back, I had written a cmdlet called Find-ChildItem which is an alternative to Get-ChildItem.

It has more options built-in such as delete files greater than some size and older than some time or delete only empty files. This might help you get rid of some additional loops and cmdlets from your script and thereby an increase in performance. You may want to give it a try.

You can get more details about this Find-ChildItem cmdlet on my blog, *[Unix / Linux find equivalent in Powershell Find-ChildItem Cmdlet](http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.in/2009/08/unix-linux-find-equivalent-in.html)* .

#### Some of Find-ChildItem's options

1. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Name ".*.exe"
2. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Name ".c$" -Exec "Get-Content {} | Measure-Object -Line -Character -Word"
3. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Empty
4. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Empty -OutObject
5. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Empty -Delete
6. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Size +9M -Delete
7. Find-ChildItem -Type d
8. Find-ChildItem -Type f -Size +50m -WTime +5 -MaxDepth 1 -Delete

I hope this helps you a bit...

Comment: This answer is from ~10 years ago.  The cited blog is still live but the download link within the blog entry is dead.